# no enclosed type error: how does it work

Tags: java, android, list

I am creating a pretty simple list of custom objects from a giant Jsonfile. This simple list contains about 1/8th to 1/10th of the original parsed JSON (that is 400 kb or so, full version is 3mb), which i can throw away. I use only the data i need in this list, so if two languages are supported, in my simple list i put only the one i need. This list i serialize so i don't need to parse all my data all the time at startup.

The object should contain some plain data, and two lists with a view custom objects in it. But my problem occurs when im trying to fill these sublist. The error is `No enclosing instance of type SimpleVenue is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type SimpleVenue (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of SimpleVenue).`

i thought i understood it, so i created an top-object, containing three objects:

1. object with plain data
2. first list of objects with two urls (strings) in it
3. second list of objects with two strings and two date objects in it.

The extra level feels a bit unnecessary actually, i wanted the two list objects to be children of the plain data object.
Anyone knows what i need to change?

my class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


public class SimpleVenue implements Serializable, Comparable<SimpleVenue>{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public SimpleVenueData simplevenuedata;
     public List <SimplePhotos> simplephotos;
      public List <SimpleOpeningHours> openinghours;

    public class SimpleVenueData implements Serializable{
        /**
         * 
         */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int ID;
    public String name;
    public String category;
    public String address;
    public String city;
    public String tip;
    public String phone;
    public String website;
    public String foursquare;
    public float latitude;
    public float longtitude;
    public String theme;
    public String icon;
    public String exception;


      //setters

public void setId(int id){
    ID=id;
}
public void setName(String vname){
name=vname;
}     
public void setCategory(String icon){
    if(icon.equals("eten.png") || icon.equals("uitgaan.png")){
        category="food";
    }else if(icon.equals("monument.png")){
        category="sights";
    }else if(icon.equals("winkelen.png")){
        category="shops";
    }
}     
public void setAdress(String vaddress){
address = vaddress;
}     

public void setCity(String vcity){
    city=vcity;
    }   

public void setTip(String vtip){
    tip=vtip;
    }
public void setPhone(String vphone){
    phone=vphone;
    }
public void setWebsite(String vwebsite){
    website=vwebsite;
    }

public void setFoursquare(String vfoursquare_link){
    foursquare=vfoursquare_link;
    }
public void setLatitude(float vlatitude){
    latitude=vlatitude;
    }

public void setLongitude(float vlong){
    longtitude=vlong;
    }

public void setTheme(String vtheme){
    theme=vtheme;
    }

public void setIcon(String vicon){
    icon=vicon;
    }
public void setException(String vexception){
     exception =  vexception;
    }

}

    public class SimplePhotos implements Serializable{
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public String medium;
        public String large;

        public void setMedium(String vmedium){
            medium=vmedium;
            }

        public void setLarge(String vlarge){
            large=vlarge;
            }
        public String getMedium(){
            return medium;
        }

        public String getLarge(){
            return large;
        }

    }

    public class SimpleOpeningHours implements Serializable{
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public String day;
        public boolean closed;
        public Date starttime;
        public Date endtime;

        //setters
        public void setDay(String vday){
            day=vday;
        }

        public void setClosed(boolean vclosed){
            closed=vclosed;
            }

        public void setStartime(Date vstarttime){
            starttime=vstarttime;
            }
        public void setEndime(Date vendtime){
            endtime=vendtime;
            }

        //getters
        public String getDay(){
            return day;
        }
        public boolean isClose(){
            return closed;
        }
        public Date getStarttime(){
            return starttime;
        }
        public Date getEndtime(){
            return endtime;
        }


    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(SimpleVenue another) {
        // XXX Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

when using:

```
  List<SimpleVenue> sv = new ArrayList<SimpleVenue>();
                                 int selectedPic;
                                 JJsonResponse e;
                                 int k =0; //indicator 1e SimpleVenue
                                 JVenueThemes jtheme;
                                 SimpleVenue tempSv;
                                 SimpleVenueData tempSvd;
                                 SimplePhotos tempPhoto;
                                 int selectedCounter;

                                 for(int i=0;i < jsonResponse.size() ;i++){
                                     e = jsonResponse.get(i);
                                     if(e.venue.hidden == false){ //staat aan
                                         for(int j=0; j<e.venue.themes.size();j++){ //loop door alle themes
                                         if (e.venue.themes.get(j).mobile == true){  //als theme is true
                                             jtheme = e.venue.themes.get(j);
                                             sv.add(new SimpleVenue());
                                             tempSv=sv.get(k);
                                             tempSvd=sv.get(k).simplevenuedata;
                                             tempSvd.setId(k);
                                             tempSvd.setName(e.venue.name);
                                             tempSvd.setAdress(e.venue.address);
                                             tempSvd.setCity(e.venue.city);
                                             tempSvd.setPhone(e.venue.phone);
                                             tempSvd.setWebsite(e.venue.website);
                                             tempSvd.setFoursquare(e.venue.foursquare_link);
                                             tempSvd.setLatitude(e.venue.latitude);
                                             tempSvd.setLongitude(e.venue.longitude);
                                             tempSvd.setCategory(jtheme.icon);
                                             tempSvd.setIcon(jtheme.icon);
                                             // language depending
                                         if (language.equalsIgnoreCase("nld")){ //dutch
                                                tempSvd.setTip(e.venue.tip); 
                                                tempSvd.setTheme(jtheme.name); 
                                             }else{ //english
                                                 tempSvd.setTip(e.venue.tip_en); 
                                                 tempSvd.setTheme(jtheme.name_en); 
                                             }
                                        // selecting pics
                                             if (e.venue.venue_photos.isEmpty() == false){
                                                for(int l=0; l < e.venue.venue_photos.size() ;l++){
                                                    selectedCounter=0;
                                                     if(e.venue.venue_photos.get(l).selected == true){ 
                                                         sv.get(k).simplephotos.add(new SimplePhotos());
//                                                       tempSv.simplephotos.add(new SimplePhotos());
//                                                       tempSv.simplephotos.get(selectedCounter).large=e.venue.venue_photos.get(selectedCounter).large;
//                                                       tempSv.simplephotos.get(selectedCounter).medium=e.venue.venue_photos.get(selectedCounter).medium;
//                                                       selectedCounter++;
                                                     }
                                                 }
                                             }else{
                                                 tempSv.simplephotos.add(new SimpleVenue.SimplePhotos());

                                                 tempSv.simplephotos.get(0).large=null;
                                                 tempSv.simplephotos.get(0).medium=null;
                                               }

                                             // selecting opening hours
                                             //testrun before entering opening hours
                                             Log.i("testrun", "k= " + String.valueOf(k));





                                             k++;
                                         }  
                                     }
                                    }
                                     jsonResponse.remove(i); // 
                                 }
```

I didn't even start make it comparable, so don't mind that. But eventually i will order my list on some items like name and theme or so.

Answer (score 0):

Do you *need* `SimpleVenueData` to have a reference to an instance of the outer class? If not, just make it a *static* nested class. (Or pull all these nested classes out entirely...)

Comment: no i didn't, i put them in their own classes now. Thank you for helping me with that. Now it didn't cause the error before running, but now i have a nullpointerexception when i add a new picture, even when its empty on this line:  tempSv.photos.add(new SimplePhotos()); do you know why? (where tempsv = the simplevenue item (like simplevenuedata in my post before))

Comment: @Jasper: Your post contains too much code for me to examine it all right now. I suggest you ask a separate question for that, having cut it down to a short but complete program showing *just* the bit which confuses you. I suspect that in coming up with that example, you'll actually work out what's wrong.